# What can the High Capacity Fuel Tanks upgrade be used for in SC2?

Tags: starcraft-2, sc2-build-order

The High Capacity Fuel Tanks upgrade allows medivac afterburners to last 50% longer. This seems like a useless upgrade, and I have never seen it being used in WCS or any other pro-game. What build is it a part of? Why does Blizzard keep it in game?

Comment: Asking why Blizzard keeps it is off-topic.  The rest...might be acceptable, if a bit broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no build High Capacity Fuel Tanks is an *essential* part of. It is indeed almost never researched, because Tech Lab time is much better put to other upgrades.

Players who specialize in heavy drop play, like TY, do sometimes get Fuel Tanks in late game, but then again, it is hard to judge whether Fuel Tanks are good, but simply least good and hence researched last, or players research them just because they can, being in a more or less comfortable late game.